# OJDBC connection with NetBeans

Tags: java, database, netbeans, oracle11g, ojdbc

I'm trying to establish a new connection with Oracle database with ojdbc7 driver and when I get to the "Customize Connection" step, i get the following message:

```
Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE using oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver (ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

)

Can anyone explain what to do? I tried putting in different formats of username and password, I tried stopping and then starting the database again (Express Edition 11g), I couldn't find anything on the web...

[image: screenshot of the mentioned step]

Comment: Well, use the correct username and password, to state the obvious. You haven't shown how you're providing those. Which account are you trying to connect to, and does that exist? The password is case-sensitive, which might trip you up, I suppose. Can you connect with the same credentials using another client - SQL\*Plus or SQL Developer, etc.?

Comment: I am creating a connection, so no username and password are yet set. Or there is something i just didn't understand properly? Are the username/pass to a database I am connecting to, or am I creating a new user?

Comment: I would say you need to have the username and password for the user you are trying to connect to, in Oracle.
Maybe some default username, like "SYSTEM" as username and password for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle has a very detailed tutorial on how to setup a connection from Netbeans to Oracle Express Edition

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/oracle-db.html

You can only connect using already existing users, If you want to create a new user you need to do that directly in the database

Regardingthe JDBC url sintax here is an example

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/xe, username = sys and password = 123456
```

Answer (score -1):

In the dependency, scope = compile to create POJO

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
            <version>${version.ojdbc6}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The issue was actually related to the URL connection. There is indeed an already accepted answer. I am glad for your attempt but please next time take a closer look at the question before providing an answer.